# Set `MainAxisSize` to min from parent widget

Tags: flutter

I've noticed that when I use a widget that internally uses a `Column`, that `Column` usually has `MainAxisSize` set to `max`.

`CupertinoFormSection` is one such widget and when I use it, my `Form` grows to fill the height of my screen and as such can't be vertically centered. It's just stuck to the top of the screen.

One possible solution to this issue might be `ConstrainedBox` but in that case, I need to specify `min/max height` that I'd have to change any time I remove or add a child to the `CupertinoFormSection`.

Any thoughts on this?

EDIT: The goal is to have the form vertically centered, without having to specify its height.

Comment: do you want to vertically center ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the best thing you can do is add an IntrinsicHeight around the form. This won't allow the form to use more space vertically. Then it needs. Then you can position the IntrinsicHeight.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html

```
return IntrinsicHeight(
    child: CupertinoFormSection(
    children: [
      // form elements go here
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: This worked and documentation suggests it's the right tool for the job. Thank you Marijn.